# Compare datatime field with current datetime in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have something like that:

```
to_days(now()) < to_days(birth)
```

It work but instead of comparing days I was to compare the time too. Is there a similar function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just use:

```
birth > NOW()
```

Comment: Because I need to subtract 15 days to the death field, than compare it:
birth <= now( ) AND now( ) < (death - 15)

Comment: Your answer is correct. I want to add the to modify a date and compare it is easy: (birth + INTERVAL 15 DAY) > NOW()
I add 15 days to birth and compare if is equal to current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for DAYOFYEAR() function ?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear